# Adwords Sitelink URLs

Tags: google-ads-api

I am working on an Adwords campaign and am looking to create ad group specific URLs. My question is best illustrated by an example:

I have Campaign #1 with Ad Group A and Ad Group B. I want both ad groups to have a sitelink with the same title but different URLs.

```
Ad Group: A /
Title: "Buy Our Widgets" / 
Destination URL: www.widgets.com/utm_adgroup=A

Ad Group: B / 
Title: "Buy Our Widgets" / 
Destination URL: www.widgets.com/utm_adgroup=B
```

When I try to upload a campaign with these settings, Adwords rejects Ad Group B's sitelink and uses Ad Group A's instead since the title of the sitelinks are the same even though the destination URLs are different. Has anyone come across this issue or know a solution to my problem? The only thing I could think of was dynamic insertion in the URLs for the adgroup name, but that does not appear to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Each extension must have a unique link text, as per Google's policy: https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/1054210?hl=en

I've just hit this problem, where I have different products in different campaigns and web domains, but they have similar website structures - eg. Buy, Download pages. My solution will be to change the links to something like "Buy Product X".